# How to package code and resources into a bundle ios

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a bunch of code and resources that I would like to share between multiple apps.

My goal is to try and get all the code and resources into a bundle, and add that bundle to all of my different apps.  However, I'm not sure if that is even possible.

Is there a way to do this or something like this in iOS apps?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

Next time try to use Google before("ios resources bundle") ;)